# Delete method is not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to hold only last 22 minute data in my DB for that i used this

```
String[] str = null;
str = new String[]{"datetime('now','-22 minute')"};
databaseInstance.delete(table_n, "datetime(modified/1000,'unixepoch')<= ?", str);
```

In database our datatype of **modified** column is as below

```
"modified" DATETIME NOT NULL
```

But it deleting all data from DB that means either of before 22 minute or after 22 minute all data get deleted from our table. But i want to hold last 22 minute data in our table .Any help is really appreciated, Please someone take me out of this issue.Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: modified is already datetime so why are you not directly compare modified and str ?

Comment: You mean to say :-    DELETE FROM "+table_n+" WHERE modified <= date('now','-22 Minute')

Comment: Yes... is there any problem for doing this way or have you try it?

Comment: i have tried this not working. I am little bit confuse modified <= date('now','-22 Minute') will work or modified <= datetime('now','-22 Minute').

Answer (score 0):

The while point of using parameters (`?`) is to *avoid* interpreting them, so that you are able to store strings containing quotes or function names in the database.

To execute the `datetime` function, it must be written directly into the SQL statement:

```java
db.delete(table_n, "datetime(modified/1000,'unixepoch') <= datetime('now','-22 minute')", null);
```

Instead of converting the table value into the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, you could convert your comparison timestamp into the same format used in the table.
This would allow an index on the `modified` column (if any) to be used:

```java
db.delete(table_n, "modified <= strftime('%s','now','-22 minutes')*1000", null);
```